# Installer Fails to Register COM Component Properly

Tags: com, installshield, dllregistration

My team recently made several changes to the VB.NET component and we are having major issues in our QA lab consistently registering the components for use in Excel. However, the "it works on my machine" syndrome is causing us major headaches.

The setup:

- C++ COM Server, uses an IDL and static guids for functions
- VB.NET Component, previously used autodual
- Installer constructed with InstallShield

The first item was that we were mandated to not use regasm to register the assembly because the installer is generated automatically on a machine using an account that lacks administrative rights. On a developer's machine (which has admin rights), we create a .reg file (`regasm /reg VBNET.dll`) and incorporate that in the installer.

The other change (that I'm responsible for) is that I refactored the VB.NET classes to move away from the use of autodual, and create specific interfaces and implementations. They have the pattern of the following code.  By doing this, are there any issues that might happen with registering a COM component?

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
<Guid("ABCD1234-FOO-BOO-ETC-GUIDHERE")> _
Public Interface ICorePoint
    <DispId(1)> Property PointX() As Double
    <DispId(2)> Property PointY() As Double
    <DispId(3)> Property PointZ() As Double
    <DispId(4)> Function Distance3D(ByVal ptB As ICorePoint) As Double
End Interface

' Implement the interface (in the same file)
<ProgId("CalculationCore_NET.CCorePoint")> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<Guid("A-DIFFERENT-GUID-HERE"> _
Public Class CCorePoint
    Implements ICorePoint
    Private m_x As Double
    Private m_y As Double
    Private m_z As Double
    Public Property PointX() As Double Implements ICorePoint.PointX
       'Implemented here'
    End Property
    'Repeat other implementations here
End Class
```

One final change is that the C++ COM Server got entirely new GUIDs as we were branching products versions. We use regsvr for this, and we've not had any issues so far.

My team is stumped and is currently trying everything from exhausting Google to draining multiple bottles of beer. I'm hoping there might be some advice/instructions on how to get us through this.

As a follow-on question, we don't register these to the GAC and have historically registered using `regasm /tlb /codebase THEDLL` . I'm not sure/I don't think the command that generated the tlb had the `/codebase` flag enabled. Could this cause major issues with what we're trying to do?

Comment: What is actually going wrong?

Comment: The primary issue is that on many machines, the VB.NET component does not register after an installation (the Excel references show as "missing". On other machines, it works perfectly fine.